# consume the string matched by look ahead in regex

Tags: c++, regex

I want to implement a negate operator in C++ and using look ahead. I can get something like `(?!xxx).*` However, Look ahead in regex does not consume any string and using `.*` will consume any string after it. Is there any better way?

For example, if I want to match a string does not end with "foo" and I implement something like `(?!.*foo).*` it will match "abcfooa" because of `.*`, which is not I want. I know in this case, I can do `(?!.*foo$).*` but in some other examples, $ is not the next character. Is there anyway to only consume what look ahead matches instead of ".*"?

Comment: Could you show one or two of the examples referred to by "...but in some other examples..."? It's generally best to begin questions with a statement in words of what you want to do, then give examples, showing the desired result for each, and then, and not before, present your code.